# How do i create a similarity matrix based on the below code?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I'm trying to use the gower function from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/gower-distance-4python/files/. I'm trying to apply it to my dataframe of categorical variables. However I can see that when i use the gower_distances function i have some non-zero values in my diagonals ( i need them to all be 0).

I've been trying to de-bug the code. I think i know where this is happening and it's occuring in the  _gower_distance_row function. There is this line of code which i don;t understand sij_cat = np.where(xi_cat == xj_cat,np.zeros_like(xi_cat),np.ones_like(xi_cat)). But i will present it in a easier format to understand.

Say i have:

```
xi=np.array(['cat','dog','monkey'])
xj=np.array([['cat','dog','monkey'],['horse','dog','hairy']])
sij_cat = np.where(xi == xj,np.zeros_like(xi),np.ones_like(xi))
```

I get this as my result:

```
array([['', '', ''],
       ['1', '', '1']], dtype='<U6')
```

since i am comparing cat with cat i want to assign zero, and where it is different e.g. cat vs horse and monkey vs hairy it should be 1. I don't get why in the above result i am getting ''? i want zeroes here. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.logical_not(xi == xj).astype(int)
```

output will be:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

explanation:
`np.logical_not` changes `True` to `False` and `False` to `True` and `astype(int)` changes to `0` and `1`